# MsgBoxResult.Yes=restart program and MsgBoxResult.no=close program Help VBA

Tags: vba, msgbox

I want my program to display a msgbox to the user that says "Would you like to try again" if bank=0 or 200. The user either chooses yes or no. Here's my code:

```
    If bank = 0 Or 200 Then
        MsgBox("Would you like to try again?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, vbYesNo)
        If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Application.Restart()
        ElseIf MsgBoxResult.No Then
            Me.Close()
            End If
```

My issue is that when someone selects "No" the program ignores "Me.Close" and instead reboots the program.

Help is appreciated...

Comment: What do you mean with "reboot" a program? I do not think that the Windows process is terminated, and started again. Probably only the form gets re-opened or something.

Comment: By rebooting I mean when the user selects "No" the program, it ignores Me.close and instead runs "Application.Restart()" as a result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Disclaimer: My answer might be wrong, because I am not a VB developer.)

As far as I understand, `MsgBoxResult.Yes` and `MsgBoxResult.No` are **constants**.

`MsgBoxResult.Yes` seems to be internally defined as some kind of non-zero integer. So the first IF-query always suceeds.

You have to get the return-value of `MsgBox()` which contains your result of what the user clicked. Then you compare this return value with the constants.

```
dim MsgBoxResultQuery As MsgBoxResult

If bank = 0 Or 200 Then
    MsgBoxResultQuery = MsgBox("Would you like to try again?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, vbYesNo)
    If MsgBoxResultQuery = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Application.Restart()
    ElseIf MsgBoxResultQuery = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: It works perfectly!. just how I intended to run the MsgBox. Thanks a lot!